# Visual Studio uses a lightning icon to represent events, is this commonly associated with events?

Tags: user-interface, icons

I'm looking for an icon to represent events and struggling a bit.

There is the 'calendar event' icon that is quite universal but my application is displaying events that occur in a vehicle and is more akin to a programming event.

Visual Studio uses the lightning icon for events, does anyone know if this is a universal icon for events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio is about the only application that uses the lightning strike icon for events.

It is not univerally recognised as representing an event.

Comment: Not really, i thinks it's due UML syntax, that require lightning bolt arrow in diagram activity. Here a piece of documentation i found about it:
Interrupting edge is activity edge expressing interruption for regions having interruptions. It is rendered as a lightning-bolt.